# Why my cost function is giving wrong answer?

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I have written a code for the **cost function** and it is giving incorrect answer.

I have read the code many times but I cannot find the mistake.

Here is my code:-

```
function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
s = 0;
h = 0;
sq = 0;

J = 0;

for i = 1:m
 h = theta' * X(i, :)';
 sq = (h - y(i))^2;
 s = s + sq;
end 

J = (1/2*m) * s;


end
```

**Example:-**

```
computeCost( [1 2; 1 3; 1 4; 1 5], [7;6;5;4], [0.1;0.2] )

ans = 11.9450
```

> Here the answer should be 11.9450 but my code is giving me this:-

```
ans =  191.12
```

I have checked the the **matrix multiplication** and the code is calculating it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood the operator evaluation order. In fact

```
1/2*m ~= 1/(2*m)
```

With this in mind it seems you're computing an average. Instead of reinventing the wheel it is usually a good idea to use the built in functions to do the job which results in a much clearer (and less error prone) implementation:

```matlab
function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
    h = X * theta;
    sq = (h - y).^2;
    J = 1/2 * mean(sq);
end
computeCost( [1,2;1,3;1,4;1,5], [7;6;5;4], [0.1;0.2] )
% ans = 11.9450
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsIwFET3OcXfCI3EmMRGkY8rd56gUCqEGqmLJpakQk8fE7txYGB4DM/30XxsSs/Z9fHlHdzgAr0f33O0Vx9i1TBYGMTBRkMJ5Az50MB2RfhDYcqsGmAHC@V3tcIiknuVn6M1rgoTRWLdg/zLoZVMoWSH3DpXdwzaEx5RY12m4BIFVx1QsgHjQlFKfq61SOkL)

Comment: Why is it giving the wrong output, isn't 1/m * 1/2 = 1/(2*m)?? Doesn't brackets are evaluated first??

Comment: Yes brackets are evaluated first and `(1/m)*(1/2) = 1/(2*m)` but `1/2*m` is evaluated as `(1/2)*m`.